# Unable to get Backbone.js route handlers to fire on matching route

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm following along the [Organizing Backbone Using Modules tutorial](http://backbonetutorials.com/organizing-backbone-using-modules/) and aside from the few tweaks I've had to make to accommodate changes to the dependencies since the article was written, I'm unable to get my .on() events to fire when a route is matched.

If you look at the index router, you'll see an alert and a console.log(). Neither is firing when the page loads. There are also no js errors.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**router.js**

```
define([
  'jquery', 
  'underscore', 
  'backbone',
  'views/index',
  'views/ideas'
], function($, _, Backbone, IndexView, IdeasView) {

  var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    '': 'index',
    '/ideas': 'showIdeas',
    '*actions': 'defaultAction'
  });

  var initialize = function() {

    console.log('this works so i know initialize() is being called');

    var app_router = new AppRouter;

    // not firing
    app_router.on('route:index', function() {
      alert('hi');
      console.log('hi');
      // var index_view = new IndexView();
      // index_view.render();
    });

    // not firing
    app_router.on('route:showIdeas', function() {
      console.log('showIdeas');
      var ideas_view = new IdeasView();
    });

    //not firing
    app_router.on('route:defaultAction', function(actions) {
      console.log('No route:', actions);
    });

    if (!Backbone.history.started ) {
      Backbone.history.start();
      console.log( "Route is " + Backbone.history.fragment );
    }
  };

  return {
    initialize: initialize
  };
});
```

Comment: what's an example of a url that's not firing one of your routes?

Comment: How about just / or more specifically, http://0.0.0.0:3000/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you put your actual routes in a routes hash on the router definition:

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '': 'index',
        '/ideas': 'showIdeas',
        '*actions': 'defaultAction'
    }
});
```

I would also add that I prefer to put the callbacks for the routes in the router definition (it's only a preference):

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '': 'index',
        '/ideas': 'showIdeas',
        '*actions': 'defaultAction'
    },

    index: function () {
        // function body here
    },

    showIdeas: function () {
        // function body here
    },

    defaultAction: function () {
        // function body here
    }
});
```

It's not required, but to me it's easier to read and see what's going on.

Comment: Ah, totally missed that. Nice catch. Thanks!